# See progress of Spotlight re-indexing in El Capitan

Tags: spotlight, macos, indexing

Other Questions and Answers address how to check the progress of Spotlight rebuilding its index, previous to El Capitan: Click the Spotlight menu. The menu/panel that appears reports a progress bar if re-indexing is in progress.

In El Capitan, that menu/panel no longer appears. Now a grey box appears in the middle of the screen where we are expected to enter our search words. The re-indexing progress bar no longer appears.

[image: screen shot of Spotlight data-entry box]

Comment: This has been asked before e.g. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155479/is-there-a-way-to-show-spotlight-indexing-status-progress-in-yosemite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type something — anything — in the gray box to reveal indexing progress:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show indexing progress; this just shows that indexing is happening. That bar is equivalent to a spinner.