# Spotlight solution stops TextEdit files opening

Tags: permission, spotlight, textedit

After running the solution for [Spotlight re-indexing takes too long or doesn't work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337706/spotlight-re-indexing-takes-too-long-or-doesnt-work) I can't save or open TextEdit files on any drive. I get the error:

> The document “anyfilename” could not be opened. You don’t have permission.
>   To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

Changing the permissions for the file, enclosing folder or drive doesn't help.

Changing the application set to open the file from TextEdit to another word processor lets me open the file OK. Changing it back means it doesn't open again.

What's going on?

Comment: Can you add a link to the solution you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks - the solution that caused this is at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337706/spotlight-re-indexing-takes-too-long-or-doesnt-work   - but I've just found that a *second* restart has fixed it. Baffled but working...