# Can't locate /.Spotlight-V100 anywhere, spotlight has incomplete results even after index rebuild

Tags: spotlight

I tried everything I could find on StackExchange and the internet, including the official apple-suggested approach of removing adding and removing the volume to privacy https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716 . This question sums up most of the things I tried [Spotlight doesn't show applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368054/spotlight-doesnt-show-applications) also this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337782/146629

One thing many tutorials mention is that you should run sudo rm -rf ./Spotlight* or ./Spotlight-V100

However, I don't have it in root and I asked around friends with newest macOS and they did not find it in root either. I would like to give it a last shot and remove that index manually before I give up and try a system restore with Time Machine, but I can't seem to find the indices anywhere. Have they moved in recent versions? Any hints on how to make spotlight work again without system restore?

I'm on 10.15.6 (19G2021)

Comment: On **macOS Catalina** it's located at: `/System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested on a **macOS Catalina 10.15.6** system, used the following *command* in **Terminal** to remove the **.Spotlight-V100** *directory*:

```
sudo rm -r /System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100
```

It deleted the **.Spotlight-V100** *directory* and in less than a minute recreated it and started indexing the system again.

Comment: Alright, can't say if this would help me, b/c I already did a time machine restore at this point to get it finally working, but I'll accept this answer, cause it's the first time I see someone writing a path on which I actually found the thing!

Comment: This continues to work in macOS monterey