# Query Spotlight indexing status from Terminal

Tags: command-line, spotlight

Is there a way to get the indexing status of Spotlight using Terminal commands?

I know that I can just press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and type anything to get a progress bar, but I would like to be able to get the same information from a shell.

PS: I'm aware of [Is there a way to show Spotlight indexing status/progress in Yosemite?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155479/is-there-a-way-to-show-spotlight-indexing-status-progress-in-yosemite) but the old question was asked for Yosemite and the existing answer regarding Terminal commands just says it wasn't possible *then*. Here's hoping that Apple improved this somehow in the meantime.

Comment: Does `mdutil -avs` work for you?

Comment: Ist works but only says if the indexing is enabled or not.

Comment: For anyone considering closing this as a duplicate, asking a new question for a new OS version is acceptable (see https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-should-we-get-a-question-updated-for-a-new-version for details). To discuss this policy please either comment **there** or ask a new question on Meta.